# c++ string template no matching function for call to basic_string<char>

Tags: c++, templates

I am writing common function to convert type T to string:

1. when T is numeric type just use std::to_string
2. when others use stringstream operator <<
3. when T is std::string just return T

```cpp
template <typename Numeric>
string to_str1(Numeric n){
    return std::to_string(n);
}

template <typename NonNumeric>
std::string to_str2(const NonNumeric& v){
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << v;
    return ss.str();
}

// if T is string just return
std::string to_str2(const std::string& v){
    return v;
}

template<typename T>
string to_str(const T& t){
    if(std::is_integral<T>::value){
        return to_str1(t);
    }else{
        return to_str2(t);
    }
}
```

test usage:

```
int a = 1101;
cout << to_str(a) << endl;

string s = "abc";
cout << to_str(s) << endl;  // should use to_str2(const std::string& v),but compile error
```

but compile error:

In instantiation of string to_str1 ..... no matching function for call to to_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string

I don't know why this error, ?

Comment: You need `if constexpr` instead of `if`, since the latter will validate both branches even if the condition is known at compile-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
if(std::is_integral<T>::value){
    return to_str1(t);
}else{
    return to_str2(t);
}
```

Then it is true that the `if` condition is either always true or always false at runtime, but it is still required that the two branches can be compiled. The first branch however doesn't work with `T = std::string`.

If you want to exclude branches from being compiled completely (aside from syntax check) based on a compile time constant, then you can use `if constexpr`:

```
if constexpr(std::is_integral<T>::value){
    return to_str1(t);
}else{
    return to_str2(t);
}
```

This tells the compiler to check the `if` condition at compile-time and only compile the branch that would be taken.

This requires C++17 or later.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that both the `if` and `else` branch will be evaluated at compile-time; you can use [Constexpr If](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if) (since C++17).

> If the value is `true`, then *statement-false* is discarded (if present), otherwise, *statement-true* is discarded.

```
template<typename T>
string to_str(const T& t){
    if constexpr (std::is_integral<T>::value){
        return to_str1(t);
    }else{
        return to_str2(t);
    }
}
```

Or overload `to_str` with the help of [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae).

```
// for integral-numbers
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, std::string>::type
to_str(T n){
    return std::to_string(n);
}

// for non-integral-numbers
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<T>::value, std::string>::type
to_str(const T& v){
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << v;
    return ss.str();
}

// if T is string just return
std::string to_str(const std::string& v) {
    return v;
}
```